# how to use boolean indexing to find value on same row but different column

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a df with 2 columns and 3 rows

```
   is_active         group_name
0       True         group_one
1       True         specific_string
2       True         group_one
```

first I checked with if the df contains a specific value in a columns

```
df['group_name'].str.contains("specific_string").any()
```

now I wanto to check if the value on the same row but on the other column is `== is_active`
I want to get boolean as return, the second line doesnt work

```
if df['group_name'].str.contains("specific_string").any():
    df.loc[df['group_name'].str.contains('specific_string').any(), 'is_active']
    return True
```

Comment: Can you create some [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In second row is used [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), so `any` is removed:

```
out = df.loc[df['group_name'].str.contains('specific_string'), 'is_active']
```

Then select first matched value by indexing:

```
return out.iat[0]
```

Comment: how to get only a bool instead of a `pandas.core.series.Series'`,                                         `Name: is_active, dtype: bool` ?

Comment: @We..are..one - I think i got it, answer was edited.